# Fatal error in the JVM with weblogic and apache camel

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, weblogic12c

I am developing a soap service with apache camel in weblogic 12.1.3. My problem is the version I have to use.

With versions 2.15.x it works perfectly (exactly version 2.15.6), but I want to upgrade to the latest compatible version for java 1.7, which is 2.17.5 and an error occurs which stops the server.

The application's java code works correctly, and the error occurs when the response is returned.

The server stops and generates a log file with the process pid. This is the error using the -verbose: class option:

```
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: illegal bytecode sequence - method not verified ================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x0000000002c85a4d, pid=12152, tid=9208
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_71-b15) (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  com.example.app.ws.jaxws_asm.StatusResponse.setReturn(Lcom/example/app/ws/response/ServiceStatus;)V+0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# J:\desarrollo\servidores\oracle-12.1.3\user_projects\domains\base_domain\hs_err_pid12152.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was
removed in 8.0
```

And the full log:

```
Loaded weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/wlserver/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentUtil from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentUtil$EnhancedMailcapCommandMap
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.attachment.ImageDataContentHandler from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapVersionFactory from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.1.9/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.staxutils.DepthXMLStreamReader from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.staxutils.PartialXMLStreamReader from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor$HeadersProcessor
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.1.9/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.evt.XMLEventFactory2 from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventFactoryImpl from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxEventFactory from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.woodstox-core-asl_4.2.0.jar]
[Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.evt.XMLEvent2 from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.BaseEventImpl from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded com.ctc.wstx.evt.BaseStartElement from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.woodstox-core-asl_4.2.0.jar]
[Loaded com.ctc.wstx.evt.SimpleStartElement from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.woodstox-core-asl_4.2.0.jar]
[Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.AttributeEventImpl from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.NamespaceEventImpl from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.CharactersEventImpl from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/org.codehaus.woodstox.stax2-api_3.1.1.jar] [Loaded org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils$StreamToDOMContext from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.cxf.annotations.SchemaValidation$SchemaValidationType from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.helpers.ServiceUtils from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.HeaderUtil from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.1.9/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.headers.Header from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.service.model.ServiceModelUtil from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.databinding.DataReader from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBase from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl$WSUIDValidationHandler
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.attachment.JAXBAttachmentUnmarshaller from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.attachment.XMLAttachmentUnmarshaller from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.attachment.AttachmentUnmarshallerAdapter
from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.UnmarshallerAwareXMLReader from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.namespaces.UnmarshalNamespaceContext
from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReaderAdapter$IndexedAttributeList
from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLStreamReaderReader$XMLStreamReaderAttributes
from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReaderAdapter$Attribute
from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.databinding.WrapperHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.WrapperHelperCompiler from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.databinding.AbstractWrapperHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBWrapperHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/3.1.9/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.model.SoapBodyInfo from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/3.1.9/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.CaseInsensitiveMap from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.component.cxf.util.CxfUtils from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-cxf/2.17.5/camel-cxf-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.spi.HeaderFilterStrategy$Direction from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.security.LoginSecurityContext from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/3.1.9/cxf-core-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultUnitOfWork from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.spi.TracedRouteNodes from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultTracedRouteNodes from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedRoute$InFlightKey
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom from
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7\jre\lib\rt.jar] [Loaded
org.apache.camel.util.UnitOfWorkHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.MessageHistory from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessageHistory from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$RedeliveryData from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInvocation from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.PipelineHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeSentEvent from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.support.LanguageSupport from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.ExpressionIllegalSyntaxException from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleBackwardsCompatibleParser from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.TokenType from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleTokenizer from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleTokenType from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleToken from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.BaseSimpleParser from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleNode from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.LiteralNode from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.BaseSimpleNode from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.LiteralExpression from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.Block from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.BlockStart from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.CompositeNodes from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.BlockEnd from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionEnd from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.UnaryExpression from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.OgnlHelper from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$64 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper$5 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper$5$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AtomicExchange from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$PreparedErrorHandler
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.ProcessorExchangePair from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor$RecipientProcessorExchangePair
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$2 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.camel.management.event.ExchangeCompletedEvent from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.DelegateAggregationStrategy from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded
org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-core/2.17.5/camel-core-2.17.5.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.selector.BaseAlternativeSelector from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/3.1.9/cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.selector.MinimalAlternativeSelector
from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/3.1.9/cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor$1 from
file:/C:/Users/xxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/3.1.9/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.9.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBValidator from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.ObjectGraph from
file:/J:/desarrollo/servidores/oracle-12.1.3/oracle_common/modules/oracle.toplink_12.1.3/eclipselink.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor158 from
__JVM_DefineClass__]
=============== DEBUG MESSAGE: illegal bytecode sequence - method not verified ================

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION (0xc0000096) at pc=0x0000000002c85a4d, pid=12152, tid=9208
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_71-b15) (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.71-b15 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# j  com.example.app.ws.jaxws_asm.StatusResponse.setReturn(Lcom/example/app/ws/response/ServiceStatus;)V+0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# J:\desarrollo\servidores\oracle-12.1.3\user_projects\domains\base_domain\hs_err_pid12152.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was
removed in 8.0
```

My service code:

```
@Component
public class WebServiceRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private String uri = "cxf:/transfer?properties.mtom-enabled=true&serviceClass=" + TransferService.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(uri)
            .to("log:input")
            .recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"));

        // service status
        from("direct:status")
            .bean(ServerStatusResponseBuilder.class);
            .to("log:output");   
    }
}

public class ServerStatusResponseBuilder {
    private static final String NA = "NA";    
    private static ServiceStatus serviceStatus = null;
    public ServiceStatus process(){
        return ServiceStatus.with(NA, NA, NA);
    }
}

public class ServiceStatus {

    private String version;
    private String environment;
    private String serverName;

    //getters & setters

    public static ServiceStatus with(String environment, String version, String serverName){   
        ServiceStatus status = new ServiceStatus();
        status.setEnvironment(environment);
        status.setVersion(version);
        status.setServerName(serverName);

        return status;
    }
}
```

My xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <!-- enable Spring @Component scan -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.app" />

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <!-- and then let Camel use those @Component scanned route builders -->
        <contextScan/>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: You will need to provide info about how your Camel route and how the response message looks like to give you better help.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti  I update my post. The code is not the problem, with version 2.15.x works fine. If you change to version 2.17.6 it fails. I can not find the reason.

Comment: I found it hard to understand based on that stacktrace what is actually going wrong. But one thing that you could try is to write ${headers.operationName} . Note the 's'. I was on 2.14 and 2.15 and sometimes header or headers gave me issues when I moved to higher versions.

Comment: The change did not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you debugged the code to see which line actually cases the app to break?

Comment: The class in which the error occurs is "org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor", in the line "Object o2 = helper.createWrapperObject (objs);" (91). After running my code from the ServerStatusResponseBuilder class.

Comment: Just a thought; you mentioned using Java 1.7 but the log seems to suggest at least something in your application is using Java 1.8 (unless I misread anything). Could this have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: I have the same problem on another computer with "Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)". The problem is the camel version.

Comment: I think it's the cxf version that includes camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper.getASMClass() is finding the ClassWriter class ("org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter") in the wrong library (probably /oracle_common/modules/asm-3.1.jar!/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.class).

You need to change the preference of the classloader in favor of the application libraries, in particular the asm library used by cxf; for example:

```
<wls:weblogic-application ...>
    ...
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
       <!-- asm.jar -->
       <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
       ...
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    ...
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

or:

```
<weblogic-web-app ...>
    ...
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
    ...
</weblogic-web-app>
```